# Payload Request on POST with $http

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to do a $http request with POST method, but Angular is sending data with Request Payload instead of Post Params. I already saw a topic to change the headers to x-www-form-urlencoded but that not solve my problem.
I created a codepen that show my problem:
http://codepen.io/rizidoro/pen/afktd

Take a look at the Developer Toolkit on Chrome. Angular is sending data with Request Payload!

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: So, instead of posting the data inside the request body you want your `{foo: "bar"}` to be appended as url query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that `Content-type` should be changed to `Content-Type`. Seems to be some case-sensitiveness bug. I'll investigate and try to post it back.